# Windows service cannot access an other windows service after alot of request In same host

Tags: c#, .net, windows, tcp

I have two windows service(names are "A" and "B") In same windows server 2012. "A" service requests a lot of times to "B" service In short time. Although these two services are available, sometimes "A" cannot access "B" and the timeout error occurs. In this time, when i try telnet to "B" service, i take success response.
The code I used is

```
              NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            string address = string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/B", hostIp, hostPort);
            EndpointAddress enpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(address);
            ServiceEndpoint endPoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IBServiceProxy)), binding, enpointAddress);
            ChannelFactory<IBServiceProxy> factory = new ChannelFactory<IBServiceProxy>(endPoint);
            IBServiceProxy bService = factory.CreateChannel();              
            bService.Send();
            factory.Close();
```

Comment: How does service A communicate with service B?

Comment: Does the timeout message mention *what resource* it couldn't obtain before the timeout? That's an important detail which should be in the question.

Comment: The error i take is "The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.". But when i look at B logs, I donot see the request from A. I think A cannot send request in this time.

Comment: I think you don0t have to create the `factory` each time

Comment: I use memory-Mapped files to talk between services